# Converting monthly data into annual and testing trend (n=5)

Tags: time-series, arima, small-sample, trend

I have a monthly data which includes seasonal and trend components for 5 years ($n=60$).
I did a test the trend of data by using ARIMA.

Does it make sense to convert into annual data ($n=5$) and then test a trend of data by using LSE?

What other methods could I use to test the trend of the data?

Comment: seasonal = always appearing in the same period, e.g. July is always the hottest month in Berlin; cycle = length of periods may differ. Every 4-6 years there is a smaller economic crisis in the US. I presume you have seasonal patterns and not a cycle.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, it has seasonal patterns.
Could you add any answer to my question?
Is it reasonal to convert monthly data to annual data?

Comment: If you doing an annual forecast than you should take annual data. If you want to look at the months there is also the option of detrending and deseasonalizing the data.

Comment: What is LSE? What kind of trend are you testing the presence of?

Comment: LSE means 'the Least Squares Estimator'.
I want to see if there exists the linear trend with time - specially in year. And if I use auunal data, it is easier to explain the result. But the p-value of annual data(n=5) can be higher than the p-value of monthly data(n=60). 
But I wonder if it is possible to use 5% p-value with the sample size of 5.